# Manually calling PDFJS functions. What func to call after PDFView.open to render

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Can´t find in the documentation what to do next.

Calling:

```
PDFView.open('/MyPDFs/Pdf1.pdf', 'auto', null)
```

I am able to see the blank pages, the loader and also the document gets the number of pages of my PDF.

The only thing is missing is the rendering.
Does anyone knows what I should call next?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain "I am able to see"? How can you see something that is not rendered? A SSCCE would be helpful.

Comment: @LarsH Have you ever used PDFJS? I can see White pages but no content printed. Just the loading  image at the center of each white page.  That is what I got. Any Idea?

Comment: 1st question - a little bit. But it's surprising how often you can help someone by just looking at the documentation with a 2nd pair of eyes. 2nd question - no, no idea. It seems to me that it's not a matter of calling another function afterwards, but I don't know how to fix the problem. Have you looked at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1507

Comment: maybe it's same behavior I could see. If you change zoom or scroll, it will render. I don't know why yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    PDFView.initialize();

    var params = PDFView.parseQueryString(document.location.search.substring(1));

    //#if !(FIREFOX || MOZCENTRAL)
    var file = params.file || DEFAULT_URL;
    //#else
    //var file = window.location.toString()
    //#endif

    //#if !(FIREFOX || MOZCENTRAL)
    if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
        document.getElementById('openFile').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('fileInput').value = null;
    }
    //#else
    //document.getElementById('openFile').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    //#endif

    // Special debugging flags in the hash section of the URL.
    var hash = document.location.hash.substring(1);
    var hashParams = PDFView.parseQueryString(hash);

    if ('disableWorker' in hashParams)
        PDFJS.disableWorker = (hashParams['disableWorker'] === 'true');

    //#if !(FIREFOX || MOZCENTRAL)
    var locale = navigator.language;
    if ('locale' in hashParams)
        locale = hashParams['locale'];
    mozL10n.setLanguage(locale);
    //#endif
    if ('textLayer' in hashParams) {
        switch (hashParams['textLayer']) {
            case 'off':
                PDFJS.disableTextLayer = true;
                break;
            case 'visible':
            case 'shadow':
            case 'hover':
                var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
                viewer.classList.add('textLayer-' + hashParams['textLayer']);
                break;
        }
    }

    //#if !(FIREFOX || MOZCENTRAL)
    if ('pdfBug' in hashParams) {
        //#else
        //if ('pdfBug' in hashParams && FirefoxCom.requestSync('pdfBugEnabled')) {
        //#endif
        PDFJS.pdfBug = true;
        var pdfBug = hashParams['pdfBug'];
        var enabled = pdfBug.split(',');
        PDFBug.enable(enabled);
        PDFBug.init();
    }

    if (!PDFView.supportsPrinting) {
        document.getElementById('print').classList.add('hidden');
    }

    if (!PDFView.supportsFullscreen) {
        document.getElementById('fullscreen').classList.add('hidden');
    }

    if (PDFView.supportsIntegratedFind) {
        document.querySelector('#viewFind').classList.add('hidden');
    }

    // Listen for warnings to trigger the fallback UI.  Errors should be caught
    // and call PDFView.error() so we don't need to listen for those.
    PDFJS.LogManager.addLogger({
        warn: function () {
            PDFView.fallback();
        }
    });

    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
    var outerContainer = document.getElementById('outerContainer');
    mainContainer.addEventListener('transitionend', function (e) {
        if (e.target == mainContainer) {
            var event = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
            event.initUIEvent('resize', false, false, window, 0);
            window.dispatchEvent(event);
            outerContainer.classList.remove('sidebarMoving');
        }
    }, true);

    document.getElementById('sidebarToggle').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          this.classList.toggle('toggled');
          outerContainer.classList.add('sidebarMoving');
          outerContainer.classList.toggle('sidebarOpen');
          PDFView.sidebarOpen = outerContainer.classList.contains('sidebarOpen');
          PDFView.renderHighestPriority();
      });

    document.getElementById('viewThumbnail').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.switchSidebarView('thumbs');
      });

    document.getElementById('viewOutline').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.switchSidebarView('outline');
      });

    document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.page--;
      });

    document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.page++;
      });

    document.querySelector('.zoomIn').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.zoomIn();
      });

    document.querySelector('.zoomOut').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.zoomOut();
      });

    document.getElementById('fullscreen').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.fullscreen();
      });

    document.getElementById('openFile').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
      });

    document.getElementById('print').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          window.print();
      });

    document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.download();
      });

    document.getElementById('pageNumber').addEventListener('change',
      function () {
          PDFView.page = this.value;
      });

    document.getElementById('scaleSelect').addEventListener('change',
      function () {
          PDFView.parseScale(this.value);
      });

    document.getElementById('first_page').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.page = 1;
      });

    document.getElementById('last_page').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.page = PDFView.pdfDocument.numPages;
      });

    document.getElementById('page_rotate_ccw').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.rotatePages(-90);
      });

    document.getElementById('page_rotate_cw').addEventListener('click',
      function () {
          PDFView.rotatePages(90);
      });

    //#if (FIREFOX || MOZCENTRAL)
    //if (FirefoxCom.requestSync('getLoadingType') == 'passive') {
    //  PDFView.setTitleUsingUrl(file);
    //  PDFView.initPassiveLoading();
    //  return;
    //}
    //#endif

    //#if !B2G

    PDFView.open(file, 0);
    //#endif
});
```

The system must be initialized first before PDFView.open call! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In viewer.js I added call to updateViewarea() after the document was downloaded.

```
    ... PDFJS.getDocument(parameters).then(
  function getDocumentCallback(pdfDocument) {
    self.load(pdfDocument, scale);
    self.loading = false;
    updateViewarea();
  }, ...
```